# How to clone tmux session to new session?

Tags: tmux

If I have a set of panes/windows in a session, can I create a new session that starts set up like the session I was just in?

Comment: You cannot create a new session, but you can detach and reattach.

Comment: You might try looking at plugin [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) or ruby program [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) to see if they can help.